# Writing content of a parallel collection to files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So, basically I want to write the content of a parallel collection in parallel. With the following code, its obviously not synchronized. What I would like though is to have exactly the same number of files as threads, so that the files could be written in parallel. How can I achieve this?

The way I could think of is to divide the parallel collection into the number of threads, and write each of that portion to a separate file. But I don't know how to do it.

```
val parMap = writerMap.par
parMap.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(NT))
parMap.foreach{case (k, content) => write_to_file(k, content)}
```